# Removing various sorts of whitespace in PHP

Tags: php, regex, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I am looking to remove multiple line breaks using regular expression. Say I have this text:

`"On the Insert tab\n  \n\nthe galleries include   \n\n items that are designed"`

then I want to replace it with

`"On the Insert tab\nthe galleries include\nitems that are designed"`

**So my requirement is:**

1. it will remove all multiple newlines and will replace with one newline
2. It will remove all multiple spaces and will replace with one space
3. Spaces will be trimmed as well

I do searched a lot but couldn't find solution - the closest I got was this one [Removing redundant line breaks with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816085/removing-redundant-line-breaks-with-regular-expressions).

Comment: here's for your space part:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Comment: @Sudhir I can remove multiple spaces but I need remove multiple newlines also.

Comment: See here:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360566/replace-multiple-newline-tab-space

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA Here is a rundown of the technique: 1) Trim the string. 2) Find all blocks of more than one white space character. 3) Iterate over them, if the block contains an `\n` character replace it with a single `\n`, if not replace it with a single space. The easiest way to do this is with `preg_replace_callback()`. I'll even give you the regex you need for free: `/\s+/`. Try and implement it yourself and if you can't get it right show what you come up with, then we can help you see what went wrong.

Comment: @Sudhir will it work for spaces in between newlines ?

Comment: @DaveRandom the text I am working on is article so can you tell me what will happen if the I have thousands of articles and millions of spaces in that articles

Comment: @ARIF see my answer, I tested it and it is working

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA Well the quantity of articles is irrelevant, because no matter how you do it, you process them 1 at a time, so you only ever need to load 1 into PCRE at once. Your second point about `millions of spaces` is a good one though, and you have made me realise that `/\s{2,}/` would be a better regex for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = trim($text);
preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);
preg_replace('/(?:\s*(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/s', "\n", $text);
```

Thanks to [Removing redundant line breaks with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816085/removing-redundant-line-breaks-with-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
echo trim(preg_replace('#(\s)+#',"$1",$string));
```

Comment: This will replace `<space>\n\n<space>` with `<space>` when it should be replaced with `\n`.

Comment: @Yazmat The key to this is to examine each token you detect in the string and see if it contains a new line, return a single new line if it does and return a space if it doesn't. I'll also give you a hint as to how you can easily do that on the fly: `preg_replace_callback()`. Also note that while your expression is sound and will work, it will be quite inefficient because you will be examining every block of whitespace (including a single character) where you only need to examine blocks of two or more whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $text); // converts Windows new lines to Linux ones
while (strpos($text, "\n\n") != false)
    {
        $text = str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $text);
    }
```

That will sort out newline characters.